# Combine Gyro and Accelerometer Readings in Rotation-Independent Way?

Tags: c++, vector, rotation, accelerometer, gyroscope

Ok, so I have my Arduino hooked up to an MPU-6050 6-axis gyro+accelerometer GY-521 breakout board. I've got it sending serial data to a program on my computer, all working perfectly. I'll pose this question in C++ even though my program is written in [DBPro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DarkBASIC_Professional).

I'm currently using a complementary filter to combine the gyro rates of angular rotation with the accelerometer gravity vector for stable yet responsive rotations. Here's my current code:

```
angleX=0.98*(angleX+(gyroX/16.4)*timeMultiplier)+0.02*atanfull(accelY,accelZ)
angleY=0.98*(angleY+(gyroY/16.4)*timeMultiplier)+0.02*atanfull(accelZ,accelX)
angleZ=0.98*(angleZ+(gyroZ/16.4)*timeMultiplier)+0.02*atanfull(accelX,accelZ)
```

`angleX/Y/Z` and `timeMultiplier` are floats. `timeMultiplier` is basically `(millis()-lastMillis)/1000.0`. `atanfull` is basically `atan2` but outputs in degrees (0-360), not radians (I think that's the only difference).

The issue is that when the board is sitting flat on the table, the accelerometer obviously can't measure rotations about the Y axis (up), but the gyro can. When I twist the board around Y, the 3D cube representation I'm rendering twists for a second then is pulled back to 0. That's because when the board is upright (with the Y axis pointing upwards) the atanfull results in 0.

What I've been scouring the internet for (but really don't know what to search) is a way to reduce the affect of the accelerometer data the less use it becomes. So as the X axis, say, is rotated so it's perpendicular to the ground (and becomes useless for measurements) the gyro is allowed more and more control, until when the X axis becomes fully perpendicular the gyro is taking no notice of the accelerometer for that axis and relies fully on the gyro.

**TL;DR**: I'm trying to find a way to combine gyro and accelerometer readings in a rotation-independent way. That is, all the implementations of gyro+accel complementary filters I can find handle pitch/roll differently to yaw, and I don't want to do that. I want to be able to turn my board in any direction and still get good readings.

I really have no idea what I should be searching for to find out how to do this, and would appreciate any help :)

Comment: "the accelerometer obviously can't measure rotations about the Y axis". Of course not. Nor can it measure rotations around the X or Z axis. And its orientation doesn't matter for this. Accelerometers measure linear acceleration.

Comment: @MSalters Well duh, but they measure the gravity vector when no linear acceleration is applied. Using `atan2` you can get rotations around the axes.

Comment: The presence of an accelerometer does suggest that linear acceleration is expected.

Comment: @MSalters I was, however, pretty specific in my question, stating that I was using `atan2` :/